# displaying key with space using Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

JSON Data key with space between the KEY
What's the best to way to display both key and value, I been stuck on this anything helps!

```
  CollegeDetails": {
            "evc edu": "http://www.evc.edu/home",
            "sj cc": "http://www.sjcc.edu/",
            "de anza": "https://www.deanza.edu/",
        }

//Simply using string Interpolation doesn't show anything
 <ul>
    <li>{{CollegeDetails}}</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: What are you trying to display over here? If you want a list, you'll need to loop through the content using `ng-repeat`

Answer (score 2):

You can do using this thing

First modify your json to replace `:` with `=`:

```
"CollegeDetails" : {
   "evc edu": "http://www.evc.edu/home",
   "sj cc": "http://www.sjcc.edu/",
   "de anza": "https://www.deanza.edu/",
}
```

to like this :

```
"CollegeDetails" = {
   "evc edu": "http://www.evc.edu/home",
   "sj cc": "http://www.sjcc.edu/",
   "de anza": "https://www.deanza.edu/",
}
```

than bind data in your `html file` like this:
`<li> {{ CollegeDetails['de anza'] }} </li>`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display the object you can use the `json` pipe:

```
<li>{{ CollegeDetails | json }}</li>
```

If you want to display a list entry per object field then you need to convert the object into a list. You can do that using `Object.keys`.

As `Object.keys` is not available in angular template expression syntax you need to expose it in your component class like this:

```
@Component({...})
export class FoobarComponent {
    //...
    keys = Object.keys;
    //...
}
```

Then in your template you can do this:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let key of keys(CollegeDetails)"><label>{{ key }}:</label> {{ CollegeDetails[key] }}</li>
</ul>
```